# List all xml nodes with a matching string in it's inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to make a search box for my website which has it's data in an xml-format.

How can I create a search through all the "v" nodes of my xml object and return all those "v" nodes that have at least one match with the search string?

In other words, if the user types in "coffee" to the text input field, I would like to return the content of every node that has the word "coffee" in it.

Here's my feeble attempt:

```js
<b n="myBook">
    <c n="1">
      <v n="1">I contain the word coffee.</v>
      <v n="2">I only have tea.</v>
    </c>
</b>
<b n="myBook2">
    <c n="1">
      <v n="1">I too contain the word coffee.</v>
      <v n="2">I too only have tea.</v>
    </c>
    <c n="2">
      <v n="1">I'm afraid I too contain the word coffee.</v>
      <v n="2">I'm happy to say I too only have tea.</v>
    </c>
</b>


function handleSearch() {
            
            var inputValue = $('.searchField').val();

            //handle search
            var searchResult = $(myxml).find('v').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == inputValue });
            console.log(searchResult);
            //would like to append the results to a div while wrapping them in paragraph tags 


  }
});

 $('.searchField').change(function() {
            
            handleSearch();
   
        });
```

```html
<input type="text" class="searchField" size="30" placeholder="Search..">
                <button type="submit">
                    <img class="submitSearch" src="search.png">
                </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want nodes with text that "contain" a certain value, you may want to change your filter function to check for the following instead:

```
$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1
```

And in case you want the search to be case insensitive, you can also change both the node text and the search inputValue to lowercase.

```
var inputValue = $('.searchField').val().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful! Ended up formulating the function like this: function handleSearch() {
            
            var inputValue = $('.searchField').val().toLowerCase();
            
            $(xml).find("v").each(function() {
                
              if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1) {
                  
                  $('main').append($(this).text());
                  
              }